# Использовать определённый коллайдер в методе соприкосновения. Unity 2D, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть на родительском объекте скрипт, в котором есть метод OnCollisionEnter2D, на этом объекте есть коллайдер, который по идее и должен участвовать в этом методе соприкосновения.

Но у меня есть дочерний объект у которого тоже есть коллайдер и в методе соприкосновения почему - то используется именно он.

**Как указать этому методу, какой именно коллайдер использовать для соприкосновения?**

Answer (score 0):

Ты можешь игнорировать коллизию с конкретным коллайдером через Physics2D.IgnoreCollision

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html

или же игноррировать коллизию между целыми слоями(Layers) через Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision.html

Comment: Physics2D.IgnoreCollision (esCol, ColPlayer); Это я указал в самом методе соприкосновения. esCol - это тот коллайдер, который должен игнорироваться в методе. ColPlayer - это та штука, которая создаётся при объявлении метода соприкосновения, вот она: void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D ColPlayer). По итогам ничего не работает, что я должен изменить, чтобы это заработало?

Comment: для начала стоит прочесть документацию как пользоватся методом, а не сунуть его в первое попавшийся под руку место.

Comment: Прочитав документацию несколько раз я всё равно не понял, что надо исправить

Comment: посмотри в пример. Где именно используется данный метод в примере? Ты должен вызывать этот метод ДО коллизии, а не когда она случилась. А то ты пытаешся игнорировать коллизию уже после того как она случилась и удивляешся почему же игнорирование не действует.

Comment: Но если использовать его вне метода соприкосновения, то как я могу получить прикреплённый коллайдер к этому методу?

Comment: Судя по вопросу тебе же нужно игнорировать один коллайдер из двоих. Вот и игнорируй один из двоих, а второй обрабатывай как нужно.

Comment: Нет, в вопросе я имел ввиду игнорирование одного объекта всем методом

Comment: что значит игнорирование одного обьекта всем методом? Я не понимаю

Comment: Изначально при написании метода соприкосновения создаётся коллайдер (в моём случае, он называется ColPlayer) Он будет равен тому коллайдеру, с которым соприкасается какой - то внутренний коллайдер. Таким образом, если я сделаю такую строку кода, которую я указал выше (то - есть буду игнорить соприкосновение между коллайдером, который НЕ должен участвовать и ColPlayer), таким образом, этот коллайдер, который НЕ должен участвовать не будет иметь к этому методу никакого отношения. Надеюсь понятно объяснил

Comment: не, все слишком сложно... Переформулирой вопрос. Обдумай его хорошо, тогда позовешь. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask вот рекомендации по задаванию вопросов.

Comment: Ладно, попробую попроще. Как мне использовать ColPlayer в других методах, а не только в этом методе соприкосновения?

Comment: Можешь найти обьект через Find. Если нужно, потом найти любой компонент в нем и использовать в любом методе, в котором тебе нужно.

Comment: Хм, а успеет ли метод соприкосновения приравнять этот посредник к ColPlayer прежде чем Start успеет проиграть строку с игнорированием, ибо в противном случае будет исключение null

Comment: Ладно, а можно ли игнорировать хотя - бы соприкосновение определённого объекта с объектом с определённым тэгом?