# Получение внутреннего коллайдера в методе OnTriggerEnter. Unity 2D, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как получить внутренний коллайдер в методе OnTriggerEnter2D? **У меня Unity версии 5.6.6** .

Под внутренним коллайдером я подразумеваю тот коллайдер, который метод соприкосновения использует для проверки соприкосновения с другими коллайдерами

(В комментариях спросили насчёт скриншота, но я решил нарисовать схемку, вот она)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я так понимаю что ваш скрип висит на объекте с этим коллайдером
и что бы взять его нужно просто вызвать GetComponent<SomeCollider>()
если я вас правильно понял

Comment: Не совсем. Думаю, если расскажу, что я вообще хочу сделать, станет  понятнее. Я хочу сделать с условие "если внутренний коллайдер (я его укажу с помощью GetComponent) не соприкасается с внешним, а соприкасается другой, то тогда выполнять условие"

Comment: все ещё не очень понятно.
Можете привести скриншот  с вашими коллайдерами, их расположением

Comment: Вообще, всё это пошло от этого вопроса. Но там никто не ответил, поэтому я решил задать вопрос по другому, но возможно это поможет, насчёт скриншота, сейчас скину - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014792/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-unity-2d-c

Comment: если  скрипт проверки на родителе то он сработает и на дочерних коллайдерах которые вступают во взаимодействие.
Как вариант можете попробовать выкрутиться так.. Используйте счетчик. Случается  попадание в коллайдер плюсуете счетчик. Каждое второе попадание будет означать ваш внутренний коллайдер. Больше ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: Рад, что вы поняли суть моей проблемы. Однако, ваш вариант выглядит костыльно, да и не факт, что взаимодействовать родительский коллайдер будет именно вторым. Во всяком случае, спасибо за отклик и предложение